# filter out properties that don't belong to a Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How can I filter out properties that don't exist on class `Car` ?

```
class Car {
    wheels: number;
    model: string;
}


const obj = {wheels:4, model: 'foo', unwanted1: 'bar', unwantedn: 'kuk'};

const goodCar = filterUnwantedProps(obj); // goodCar only has fields wheels and model
```

How can I retain on `obj`, only the fields that exist on class `Car` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce()` on keys of new instance of `Car` class and take only properties that exists on object.

```js
class Car {
  constructor() {
    this.wheels = Number();
    this.model = String();
  }
}

const obj = {
  wheels: 4,
  model: 'foo',
  unwanted1: 'bar',
  unwantedn: 'kuk'
};


var goodObj = Object.keys(new Car)
  .reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e in obj) r[e] = obj[e];
    return r;
  }, {});

console.log(goodObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use contructor:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(wheels, model) {
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.model = model;
  }
}

const obj = {wheels:4, model: 'foo', unwanted1: 'bar', unwantedn: 'kuk'};

const goodCar = new Car(obj.wheels, obj.model);

console.log(goodCar);
```

OR:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.wheels = obj.wheels;
    this.model = obj.model;
  }
}

const obj = {wheels:4, model: 'foo', unwanted1: 'bar', unwantedn: 'kuk'};

const goodCar = new Car(obj);

console.log(goodCar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and returning the object from the function:

```
const filterUnwantedProps = function({
  wheels: wheels,
  model: model
}) {
  return {
    wheels: wheels,
    model: model
  }
};
```

Sample code:

```js
class Car {
  wheels: number;
  model: string;
};

const obj = {
  wheels: 4,
  model: 'foo',
  unwanted1: 'bar',
  unwantedn: 'kuk'
};

const filterUnwantedProps = function({
  wheels: wheels,
  model: model
}) {
  return {
    wheels: wheels,
    model: model
  }
};
const goodCar = filterUnwantedProps(obj);
console.log(goodCar);
```